# iis as a reverse proxy server for kestrel

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, kestrel

I want to use iis to be reverse proxy for my asp.net core 1.x application and available whit http://localhost:5000 url in the server and it be available on the Internet with http://example.com
But there is a problem that makes I can not do it.
It's program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();

    }
```

and it's my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 

   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore"/> 
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\exampleApp.exe" arguments=".\exampleApp.dll"  stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
   </system.webServer>    

</configuration>
```

What is my problem?Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is a problem"? What exactly is it? If you don't even know how to properly describe a problem, go back and learn from others.

Comment: Have you installed the hosting services? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime (under Windows Server Hosting (x86/x64)). Without it, you can't host ASP.NET Core in IIS as reverse proxy

Comment: Thanks for your tips,but I have installed .NET Core 2.0 SDK and my site doesn't lunch ,but with localhost url is accessible and exampleApp.exe run, when I browse domain name IIS default page shown.My question is how to bind example.com to localhost:5000 and exampleApp.exe runs to show my site own pages?

Comment: Babak iran nezhad, to get your website working with the domain you'll need to setup dns records. Have you done this yet?

Comment: @TidyDev,Yes I did it and in the internet when I browse example.com IIS page of my server shown and it's determine that dns is successfully resolve I want to know how to bind example.com in the server to my website and doesn't shown iis page, Are you think it's related to IIS or my be my web.config has mistake ?